# Using 'or' in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I can find where my DataFrame has `ALEX` or `KIM` in the name column by using

```
df.query('Name=="ALEX" or Name=="KIM"')



        Name    Gender
4556    ALEX    ('male', 'female')
4560    KIM ('female', 'male')
```

However, when I use `df[df.Name==('ALEX' or 'KIM')]`, the following is returned:

```
        Name    Gender
4556    ALEX    ('male', 'female')
```

and when I use `df[df.Name==('ALEX' and 'KIM')]` the following is returned:

```
        Name    Gender
4560    KIM ('female', 'male')
```

So, i) How can I find where `Name` is ALEX or KIM in a purely pythonic way, and ii) why does the logic behave the way it does for the last two examples?

Comment: Why do you feel like `Name=="ALEX" or Name=="KIM"` is not "pure Pythonic"?

Comment: I meant without using the query command.  I'm interested in getting the same result using the style in the last two examples.

Comment: Try `df[(df.name = "ALEX") or (df.name ="KIM")]`

Comment: @DarkMatter That doesn't work. The answer given by ayan does what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element-wise `or` operator in pandas is `|`. `or` operator does not work because it makes a comparison against the whole series `df.Name` (thus returns a single value). You can use the element-wise operator like this:

```
df[(df.Name == "ALEX") | (df.Name == "KIM")]
```

Or, you can use the `isin` method:

```
df[df.Name.isin(["ALEX", "KIM"])]
```

Comment: How can I use and insted of or here

Comment: The operator is `&`. `df[(df.Name == "ALEX") & (df.Gender == "F")]`

Comment: Ya got it ...thanx ..:)